# Action en primefaces no me redirecciona

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Página inicial:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="index.css"/>
        <link href="./resources/css/GrowlInicioRed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="./resources/css/Tema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="header">
            <h:form id="signup"
                    style="text-align: center; margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%;">
                <p:growl id="growl" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>

                <h:graphicImage value="imagenes/businessman223.png" width="50" height="50"/>
                <br></br><br></br>

                <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="txtUsuario" value="Usuario"/>

                    <p:inputText id="txtUsuario" required="true" value="#{indexBean.usuario.nombre}"
                                 requiredMessage="Usuario obligatorio"/>

                    <p:outputLabel for="txtClave" value="Clave"/>

                    <p:password id="txtClave" required="true" value="#{indexBean.usuario.password}"
                                feedback="true"
                                promptLabel="Digite su contraseña Por Favor" weakLabel="Minimo"
                                goodLabel="Medio" strongLabel="Maximo" requiredMessage="Clave obligatoria"/>

                    <p:commandButton value="Iniciar Sesion" icon="ui-icon-key"                                 
                                     actionListener="#{indexBean.listenerBotonInicioDeSesion()}"
                                     process="@this txtClave,txtUsuario" 
                                     action="principal"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

principal.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Principal</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="index.css"/>
        <link href="./resources/css/GrowlInicioRed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="./resources/css/Tema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>        
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form style="width:400px;"id="Inicio-Modulo">
            <p:growl id="growl" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true"/>
            <h4>BIENVENIDO A MODULO SEFARCOL<p></p>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Veo que tienes esto: `<p:commandButton value="Iniciar Sesion" actionListener="#{indexBean.listenerBotonInicioDeSesion()}" action="principal" ... />`. Creo que lo mejor sería que proveas el código de tu managed bean y lo ordenes un poco, pienso que solo deberías utilizar `action` para realizar tu acción y devolver el nombre de la vista donde quieres navegar, asimismo quitar la acción ajax que provee `<p:commandButton>` por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es que tu `UICommand` `<p:commandButton>` tiene funcionalidad ajax por defecto. Deshabilita esta funcionalidad vía `ajax="false"`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Iniciar Sesion" icon="ui-icon-key"
    actionListener="#{indexBean.listenerBotonInicioDeSesion()}"
    process="@this txtClave,txtUsuario"
    action="principal" ajax="false" />
```

Asimismo, es mejor utilizar `action` en lugar de `actionListener` para ejecutar la acción del `UICommand` y devolver el resultado de tu navegación como resultado en el método. Esto sería así.

Código facelets:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{indexBean.inicioSesion}" ... />
```

Código Java:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class IndexBean {
    public String inicioSesion() {
        /* código para validar sesión del usuario */
        return "principal";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto en los casos de login, es primero que nada un `<welcome-file-list>` al archivo `web.xml`, las que definirán las rutas en caso se inicie sesión. Si se está usando Spring Security, al inicio de sesión será redirigido a la primera de las rutas accesibles de esa lista.

Por otro lado, y siguiendo la hipótesis de que estás usando Spring Security no es necesario usar el atributo action en el `commandButton`, pero sí es necesario desactivar el `ajax` y cambiar tipo a `submit`, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
    <p:commandButton value="Iniciar Sesion" icon="ui-icon-key"      
        actionListener="#{indexBean.listenerBotonInicioDeSesion()}"
        process="@this txtClave,txtUsuario" ajax="false" type="submit"/>
```

El atributo `action` depende de si usa o no Spring Security como framework de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Te debería funcionar de esta manera:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{beanManejado.accionRedireccionar}" value="Volver" />
```

Y en tu bean de esta manera:

```
public String accionRedireccionar() {

    return "<carpeta_dentro_WEBINF>/pagina.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto, no es necesario implementar un método en el *Bean* para ***action*** más que para hacer programática tu redirección pero eso depende de tu lógica, sin embargo, siento que no has definido tus reglas de navegación en tu **faces-config.xml**.

Deberías usar algo como lo siguiente:

```
<navigation-rule>
     <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
     <navigation-case>
           <from-outcome>principal</from-outcome>
           <to-view-id>/portal/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect include-view-params="true"></redirect>
     </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

De hecho, la manera en que usas `actionListener` y `action` son las más aconsejables.

Comment: Puedes poner tu canal de Youtube en la información del perfil, si no es mucha molestia, no pongas el enlace en cada respuesta.

Comment: Buena idea, saludos.